# flexbox items do not expand to their max width

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors, styles

I want the flex items on the first row to shrink to a certain point defined by flex basis and after that to wrap and I want them to grow until max width is reached and then to unwrap but they start unwrapping sooner. What makes them unwrap at around 260px
https://codepen.io/sevgin0954/pen/mdmxZzx

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
     <div class="item"></div>
 </div>

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
    flex: 1;
    flex-basis: 170px;
    max-width: 400px;

    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox introduces `auto` as the initial value of `min-width`. When overflow is visible, that **auto forces the flex item to grow** so that its content doesn't overflow.

Therefore, you can use `min-width: 0`  
However, it won't maintain its aspect ratio. To fix that, you can use
`object-fit`

```
.container {
    object-fit: contain;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

This will maintain the expected ratio for the item then you can make sure that it follows the outcome you expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my issue and allowed me to answer my own question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77646072/how-to-prevent-a-flex1-div-from-expanding-to-fill-its-large-contents/77646602#77646602

If I could nominate this for accepted answer I would!