# How to prevent a flex:1 div from expanding to fill its large contents?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a situation where I need two columns, one of 150px and one to fill the remaining space and have the content inside it scroll (only if the content is larger than can fit in the div of course). I'm attempting to use flexbox for this, but the result is always expanding further and ignoring the max width.

How would I adjust this to fill the remaining space and be limited to that remaining space please? Thanks.

I should say, before people say "Just set it to 150px explicitly as that's what is remaining", the 300px limit is dynamic for responsive breakpoints, so I'm trying to avoid calculating the remaining width on every resize.

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="first-column">
    Small content
  </div>
  <div class="second-column">
    <div class="scrolling-container">
      <div class="scrolling-container-large-content">
        My large content is here and this is the issue that's causing it to go beyond the default flex width
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.first-column {
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second-column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.scrolling-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Result (larger than 300px):
[image: The result]

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving this thanks to the answer posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68701737/1616987

As mentioned in that answer, using flexbox sets the default min-width of the children elements to auto, which means they expand to fit their contents.

Setting the min-width to 0 for the appropriate element solved my issue. My CSS now looks as follows:

```
.outer-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.first-column {
  width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.second-column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0; /* Added this */
}

.scrolling-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

New (and correct) result:
[image: Correct result]